# Workbooks.Open method giving run time 9 when file exists (Dir(file_string) works)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim savepath as String
Dim dfile as String
Dim wb as Workbook

'strings setting omitted

If Not Dir(savepath & dfile) <> "" Then
  MsgBox "Cannot find the file."
End If

Set wb = Workbooks(savepath & dfile)
wb.Open
'Workbooks(savepath & dfile).Open also fails
```

I'm getting a run-time error 9 despite the Dir() not raising the messagebox.  I can copy and paste the concatenated string into Windows Explorer bar and the excel file opens, so the file certainly exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you omit the string settings? How do we know if you have those correct?

Comment: The Workbooks collection only includes *open* workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

`Workbooks` only includes open workbooks.  To open a workbook you use `Workbooks.Open(pathToFile)`

```
Dim savepath as String
Dim dfile as String
Dim wb as Workbook

'strings setting omitted

If Dir(savepath & dfile) = "" Then
      MsgBox "Cannot find the file."
Else
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(savepath & dfile)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest changing your code mainly in the if condition to:

```
Dim savepath as String
Dim dfile as String
Dim wb as Workbook

'strings setting omitted

strFilename = Dir(savepath & dfile)
If Len(strFilename) > 0 Then
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(savepath & dfile)
Else
  MsgBox "Cannot find the file " & dfile & " in " & savepath & "."
End If
```

This way you also assure, that `Open` only happens when file actually exists and i think putting the positive case on top and the error on bottom is more readable.

you could also write

```
If Dir(savepath & dfile) <> "" Then
```

but for a quick brief review of code, something like `NOT fn() <> ""` is not as understandable

Comment: `wb.Open` is not a thing in VBA